# If I use a v-for on a text input tag, can I get the values that were inserted?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to get the values that were inserted on text input tags that were generated by a v-for?

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="item in formItems" :key="item">
<label for="exampleFormControlInput1">{{item.label}}</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="exampleFormControlInput1">
```

I know that if you create the input tags by hand you can access the value with a v-model to a variable. Can I somehow get the values from input tags that were generated from a v-for?

Context: I was trying to do a generic vue form component and it would generate input tags depending on how many were needed. I would therefore submit the inserted values but I dont know how to access the inserted values in this specific case. Should I just make individual forms and not attempt to use a generic one or is there a way?

Comment: like `v-model="item.myString"` ?

Comment: Thats how I do when I create inputs one by one, but how do I do something similar when the inputs are created by a v-for loop that creates several inputs, how do I get the values that are intruced after?

Answer (score 0):

Add the values to your configuration object and add a value attribute to each field. Alternatively you can have a separate configuration object array and a values array, and match them with the index of your field.

```
export default {
  name: "child1",

  data() {
    return {
      formItems: [
        {
          label: "test1",
          value: "",
        },
        {
          label: "test2",
          value: "",
        },
      ],
    };
  },

  computed: {
    allValues() {
      return this.formItems.map(({ value }) => value);
    },
  },

  methods: {
    addField(label, value = "") {
      this.formItems.push({
        label,
        value,
      });
    },
  },
};
```

In this example we start off with two fields. The button adds new fields by modifying `formItems`. `allValues` is an example of a computed property that gets all the values. You probably want to loop over `formItems` though in an actual application so you know what field the value belongs to. If you get your fields from an api, modify the response in such a way that you have all the information that belongs to a field in one 'field' object, so you can easily access it and process it later once values have changed.

[image: Edit If I use a v-for on a text input tag, can I get the values that were inserted?]